# How do I use the pipeline from stream-json to write to file, in nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-streams

I'm trying to use [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json) to read a zip, unzip it, and then write it to file. I don't think I understand how to use the library.

Based on the link above, they have this example:

```js
const {chain}  = require('stream-chain');

const {parser} = require('stream-json');
const {pick}   = require('stream-json/filters/Pick');
const {ignore} = require('stream-json/filters/Ignore');
const {streamValues} = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamValues');

const fs   = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');

const pipeline = chain([
  fs.createReadStream('sample.json.gz'),
  zlib.createGunzip(),
  parser(),
  pick({filter: 'data'}),
  ignore({filter: /\b_meta\b/i}),
  streamValues(),
  data => {
    const value = data.value;
    // keep data only for the accounting department
    return value && value.department === 'accounting' ? data : null;
  }
]);

let counter = 0;
pipeline.on('data', () => ++counter);
pipeline.on('end', () =>
  console.log(`The accounting department has ${counter} employees.`));
```

However I don't want to count anything, I just want to write to file. Here is what I have that works:

```js
function unzipJson() {
  const zipPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'AllPrintings.json.zip');
  const jsonPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'AllPrintings.json');
  console.info('Attempting to read zip');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let error = null;
    Fs.readFile(zipPath, (err, data) => {
      error = err;
      if (!err) {
        const zip = new JSZip();
        zip.loadAsync(data).then((contents) => {
          Object.keys(contents.files).forEach((filename) => {
            console.info(`Writing ${filename} to disk...`);
            zip.file(filename).async('nodebuffer').then((content) => {
              Fs.writeFileSync(jsonPath, content);
            }).catch((writeErr) => { error = writeErr; });
          });
        }).catch((zipErr) => { error = zipErr; });
        resolve();
      } else if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

However I can't easily add any processing to this, so I wanted to replace it with `stream-json`. This is my partial attempt, as I don't know how to finish:

```js
function unzipJson() {
  const zipPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'myfile.json.zip');
  const jsonPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources', 'myfile.json');
  console.info('Attempting to read zip');
  const pipeline = chain([
    Fs.createReadStream(zipPath),
    zlib.createGunzip(),
    parser(),
    Fs.createWriteStream(jsonPath),
  ]);
  // use the chain, and save the result to a file
  pipeline.on(/*what goes here?*/)
```

Later on I intend to add extra processing of the json file(s), but I want to learn the basics before I start throwing in extra functionality.

I can't produce a minimal example unfortunately, as I don't know what goes into the `pipeline.on` function. I'm trying to understand what I *should* do, not what I've done wrong.

I also looked at the related `stream-chain`, which has an example that ends like so:

```js
// use the chain, and save the result to a file
dataSource.pipe(chain).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.txt.gz'));`
```

But at no point does the documentation explain where `dataSource` comes from, and I think my chain creates it's own by reading the zip from file?

How am I supposed to use these streaming libraries to write to file?

Comment: If you want to write a json file and not change anything in it, you don't have to parse it at all. Treat it like any other text file. `json-parser` does not need to be involved in unzipping.

Comment: `chain([fs.createReadStream(zipPath), zlib.createGunzip(), fs.createWriteStream(jsonPath)]);` or `fs.createReadStream(zipPath).pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(jsonPath));` should do it.

Comment: "*`pipeline.on(/*what goes here?*/)`*" - error handling and waiting for the pipeline to finish.

Comment: @bergi does creating the chain execute it? I though it just defined what to do when it was called/executed/activated etc?

Comment: I don't know the `stream-chain` library, but in general calling `pipe` does start the stream

Comment: @bergi are you suggesting I should try `chain.pipe()`?

Comment: No, mainly I'm suggesting you should drop `stream-json`. And you'll find dozens of examples for how to unzip a file in a streaming fashion with nodejs.

Comment: @bergi, I appreciate the suggestion, but as I'm interested in learning how to use this specific library, so suggesting not to use it isn't helpful (it's not unhelpful though, either)

Comment: Sorry, but "*use stream-json to read a zip, unzip it, and then write it to file*" just doesn't make sense. You don't need to use that library unless you want to actually process the JSON data somehow.

Comment: @bergi, the reason I'm learning the library is so I can do processing later on. I'm replacing existing code that does work, because I couldn't modify it to do processing at the same time cleanly. I'm trying to walk before I can run, so I've not included any of the processing in this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237004/discussion-between-pureferret-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to count anything, I just want to write to file

In that case, you'll need to convert the token/JSON data stream back into a text stream that you can write to a file. You can use the library's [`Stringer`](https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/Stringer) for that. Its documentation also contains an example that seems to be more in line with what you want to do:

```
chain([
  fs.createReadStream('data.json.gz'),
  zlib.createGunzip(),
  parser(),
  pick({filter: 'data'}), // omit this if you don't want to do any processing
  stringer(),
  zlib.Gzip(),            // omit this if you want to write an unzipped result
  fs.createWriteStream('edited.json.gz')
]);
```

Comment: You said: "I don't know the stream-chain library, but in general calling pipe does start the stream", can you show an example of calling pipe?

Comment: @Pureferret See the documentation of the [stream-chain package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-chain) and the [node stream api](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_modes)

Comment: I had already read those, which is why I asked here. If you don't know that's ok, I can wait for another answer. If it helps, I've updated my question.

Comment: @Pureferret Not sure what the problem is. Does the code not work? I would think `stream-chain` does the piping itself if used with a readable stream as the first value and a writable stream as the last value.

Comment: intially I thought it wasn't working because of an error, but I think my error is to do with my zip format. Thanks for clearing up what ended up being a silly bit of confusion on my part!